# Rigify Custom Bones Won't Display, Displays Octahedral Ones Instead?

Tags: rigging, rigify

So I was working on my character mesh and all the sudden the controls (custom bones) for the Rigify Rig disappeared. I have used it to make animations before and the animations still work.

The Rig's octahedral bones are showing up instead of the controls (custom bones). I think the problem might have something to do with the Rig being disconnected from the Rig's WGTS objects. Here is what it looks like now:
[image: Rigify Control Issue]

How can I get the controls to show up again and/or connect them to the Rig's bones?
Thanks :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130880/discussion-on-question-by-markus-vaittinen-rigify-custom-bones-wont-display-di).